# How do SQL Server full join return a extra row in this case?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Simple schema:

```
CREATE TABLE T (A INT, B INT)
```

With 5 rows inserted into the table:

```
INSERT INTO T VALUES (1,1), (2, NULL), (NULL, 3), (4,4), (5,5);
```

The following query returns 6 lines, when I thought it would return only 5:

```
SELECT * FROM T X FULL JOIN T Y ON X.A = Y.A;
```

Result:

```
|      A |      B |      A |      B |
|--------|--------|--------|--------|
|      1 |      1 |      1 |      1 |
|      2 | (null) |      2 | (null) |
| (null) |      3 | (null) | (null) |
|      4 |      4 |      4 |      4 |
|      5 |      5 |      5 |      5 |
| (null) | (null) | (null) |      3 |
```

Why this happens? How this last line got returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your table there is this row:

```
NULL 3
```

which by this condition:

```
ON X.A = Y.A
```

does not match any other row of the table.
In this case the self `FULL` join returns 1 row from the 1st copy (`X`) of the table which is the 3d row of your results:

```
(null) |      3 | (null) | (null)
```

(the last 2 `null` columns indicate that the row is not matched)
and another row from the 2nd copy (`Y`) of the table which is the 6th row of your results:

```
(null) | (null) | (null) |      3
```

(the first 2 `null` columns indicate that the row is not matched)

Comment: So when `x.a` is null and `y.a` is null, they got compared but doesn't match even with those two values being null?

Comment: `null` is not equal to `null` if this is what you want to know. `null` represents *unknown* or *missing*.

Comment: Here is a good link about this subject: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1017058/Handle-NULL-in-SQL-Server

Answer (score 2):

The record `(NULL, 3)` was not matched by any value in `X`. Since this is a `FULL JOIN`, all records from both tables are returned at least once, even if they are not matched.

Answer (score 2):

The FULL JOIN keyword returns all matching records from both tables whether the other table matches or not. So, if there are rows in 'X' that do not have matches in 'Y', or if there are rows in 'Y' that do not have matches in 'X', those rows will be listed as well.

In sql NULL is not equal to NULL so X.A=Y.A condition is not true where A is null, which is the third row of T.

Answer (score 1):

You have to understand the FULL OUTER JOIN :

> A full outer join returns the matched rows, which are normally
> returned from an inner join; plus rows from the left that don’t have
> matches in the right, with NULLs used as placeholders in the right
> side; plus rows from the right that don’t have matches in the left,
> with NULLs used as placeholders in the left side. It’s not common to
> need a full outer join because most relationships between tables allow
> only one of the sides to have rows that don’t have matches in the
> other, in which case, a one-sided outer join is needed.

[image]